# Ubuntu with Postfix mail forwarding, DNS records (MX, SPF, DKIM) needed?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, email, postfix, ubuntu-16.04

I've a server at [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) with Ubuntu 16.04.1, configured it with [Serverpilot](https://serverpilot.io/) and it's working great! Let's say I'm hosting a website `domain.com` which is sending emails with [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). So my DNS records for this domain are:

```
A     @             123.123.123.123
A     www           123.123.123.123
CNAME mail          some-sendgrid-domain.com
CNAME s1._domainkey some-sendgrid-domain.com
CNAME s2._domainkey some-sendgrid-domain.com
```

Now I'd like to have a mail forwarder: `test@domain.com` to my `@gmail.com` address. Serverpilot installs Postfix by default so I just have to configure the forwarding right?

- `vi /etc/postfix/main.cf`

  - `virtual_alias_domains = domain.com`
  - `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`
- `vi /etc/postfix/virtual`

  - `test@domain.com address@gmail.com`
- `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
- `service postfix reload`

Now I also need a MX record because Postfix is receiving emails:

```
MX @ domain.com - prio 10
```

This should do the job? And what about SPF and DKIM? Is that necessary for forwarding to Gmail? Because every other mail will be send through SendGrid.

This didn't work (no errors in the postfix log and no mails in my Gmail), so I'm now using http://improvmx.com/ for the time being but I'd like to be explicit about my forwarders instead of a catch all.

What's going wrong here? Or what alternatives are there? I prefer to not self host my email, that's why I'm using SendGrid but I just need some forwarders...

Comment: When you test, what are the headers of your incoming test email:  Is there a DKIM signature header? The standard "From" header points to some from-domain. Is there SPF or DKIM or DMARC on this from-domain? Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a alternative for SendGrid: [Mailgun](https://mailgun.com/) which makes it possible to also receive emails, see: https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#receiving-forwarding-and-storing-messages. This way I don't have to do anything with mail on my server.

**Edit:** I just wrote a blog post about this: https://royduineveld.nl/free-email-forwarding/